# Creating a floating tree next to another

Tags: tikz-trees, forest, linguistics

I'd like to draw a smaller subtree inside a circle stemming out of this tree, in the following way:
[image]

Is there a code I can use to do that (I'm using forest)?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: It would be helpful to provide a compilable document for for the tree you have and then we can help you with the rest.

Comment: The easiest but not fully automatic way: Put the smaller tree in a savebox and use that inside a circular node that is placed at the appropriate node in the big tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are three ways to do this. The first two allow the tree in the circle to be different from the main tree. The third method uses the TikZ `spy` library to literally create a snapshot of the larger tree, in which case the tree inside the circle will necessarily be the same as the main tree.

### Using a `\savebox`

By far the simplest way to do this is to save the smaller tree in a `\savebox` and then add it as a separate node beside the tree:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\newsavebox{\mysubtree}
\savebox{\mysubtree}{
\begin{forest}
[CP [C] [TP [T] [vP]]]
\end{forest}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
[CP [C ] [TP,name=TP [DP] [T' [T ][vP [DP ][v' [v] [VP [V ] [DP ]]]]]]]
\node[draw,red,thick,circle,right=1cm of TP] (savedTree) {\usebox{\mysubtree}};
\draw[->,red,thick] (TP) -- (savedTree);
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of \savebox code]

### Using the `tikzmark` package

A similar but slightly more complicated way to do this is to use the TikZ `fit` library (loaded by `forest`) to make a circled set of nodes, and then use the  `tikzmark` package to connect the two trees. This requires at least two compilations to work properly because it uses the `[remember picture]` functionality. It also requires a bit of manual calculation to position the trees, which doesn't seem very practical.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
[CP [C ] [\subnode{TP}{TP} [DP] [T' [T ][vP [DP ][v' [v] [VP [V ] [DP ]]]]]]]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
[CP,name=CP [C] [TP [T] [vP,name=vP,]]]
\node[draw,red,thick,circle,fit=(CP) (vP),remember picture] (subTree) {};
\end{forest}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[->,red,thick,] ($(pic  cs:TP)+(.5,0)$) -- ($(pic cs:subTree)+(-3.75,-1)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of tikzmark code]

### Using the `spy` library

The third method allows you to simply magnify a portion of the tree. This means that the tree in the circle can't be different from the main tree, and so may not be as useful, but I include it here for completeness.  Since the default `spy` styles put a circle around both the node spied on and the node the spy is in, I've made a new style that removes the circle around the part spied on in the main tree.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\tikzset{spy using no node/.style=
{spy scope = {
every spy on node/.style={circle},
every spy in node/.style={draw,circle,red,thick},
spy connection path={\draw[thick,red,->] (tikzspyonnode) -- (tikzspyinnode);},
#1
}
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using no node = {magnification=1,size=3.5cm},connect spies]
\begin{forest}
[CP [C ] [TP,name=TP [DP] [T' [T ][vP [DP ][v' [v] [VP [V ] [DP ]]]]]]]
\spy on (TP) in node at ($(TP)+(.5cm,0cm)$);
\end{forest}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of spy code]